# Is there an ellipse with rational major and minor axes which has a "simple" closed form perimeter?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

Other than the trivial case of an ellipse with equivalent major and minor axes (a circle) or the degenerate case where one axis is $0$, is there any known ellipse that has rational length major and minor axes and whose perimeter can be represented in closed form as either an algebraic number, or else an algebraic multiple of $\pi$?*

If, by some chance, the answer is yes and such an ellipse is possible I would very much like to know what proportions one such ellipse has.

EDIT: *Or more generally, an algebraic multiple of an algebraic power of $\pi$.

Comment: Related: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegralSingularValue.html

Comment: Simply set the formula for an ellipse arc length equal to the number you want and solve for the axis length.

Comment: @TymaGaidash:  That won't necessarily yield a rational axis length given an algebraic arc length, which is what the OP wants.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert the arc length does not have to be rational.  I am entirely content with either an algebraic length or an algebraic multiple of pi.

Comment: Can the arclength have powers of pi and rational arguments of the factorial?

Comment: It's my understanding that factorial isn't really a closed form any more than an integral is.

Comment: With $(x,y)=(a\cos t,b\sin t)$, the problem is to solve for $a\ne b$ and given $L$ in:
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{a^2\sin^2t+b^2\cos^2t}\,dt = L
$$
This is equivalent with finding a number $r=b/a$ with e.g. the major axis given as well such that
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{\sin^2t+r^2\cos^2t}\,dt = L/a
$$
Solutions of the latter certainly can be found numerically.

Comment: @HandeBruijn Numerically? Such that all unknowns are of the form $p \pi^q$ where p and q are algebraic numbers?

Comment: No, just solving for real-valued $r$. That's why this comment is not formulated as an answer :-(

Comment: Equivalently: does there exist $k\in\Bbb Q$ such that ${}_2F_1(-1/2,1/2;1;k^2)\in\Bbb A\cup\Bbb A/\pi$ where $\Bbb A$ is the set of algebraic integers?

Comment: The Askey scheme might be useful for this.